# Please Help: Non-functional color settings in Style menu

Tags: pine-script

(Update 4/8/21:  It's been over 3 months since I submitted this problem to TV support, and it still isn't resolved, in spite of my following up several times.  I see this problem affecting countless scripts.  Does anyone have any suggestions???)

It seems something has recently changed in the way pine is read.  When I go into the Style menu for the plot shown below I get six different color options #0-5. Only color #0 does anything.

Is there a way to prevent these seemingly non-functional settings from being displayed in the Style menu??
Many Thanks in advance!!

```
//  ----------------------------------------------
Color_Boxes_Long_Both_DB = if (close > open)
    color.fuchsia
else
    na
    

plotshape(series = -Plot_Loc_Lower_SR, title = "(Lower Pane - DB Overlayed Mode) Bull S/R", location=location.absolute, style = shape.circle, 
  size=size.tiny, color = Color_Boxes_Long_Both_DB, transp = Transparency_SR_DB)
//  -----------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I Rec'd a response from TV support:
"Hi!
We’ve identified the issue and assigned a task to our tech team already. We’ll let you know once there is an update.
Thanks for your patience and our apologies for the inconvenience."

Answer (score 1):

FIXED!! 4/9/21  Creating a series for the color definition functions as a work-around for the bogus colors in the Styles menu.  Note:  Unless ALL plotshapes (my indy had multiple ) are defining colors in this way, the bogus colors will return. I haven't tested other types of plots to see if All plots require this format, or just plots of the same type.

```
//  -----------------------------------------------
//  The Fix:
Color_Boxes_Long_Both_DB() => close > open

plotshape(series = -Plot_Loc_Lower_SR, title = "(Lower Pane - DB Overlayed Mode) 
Bull S/R", location=location.absolute, style = shape.circle, 
  size=size.tiny, color = Color_Boxes_Long_Both_DB() ? color.fuchsia : na, transp 
 = Transparency_SR_DB)
//  -----------------------------------------------
```

[image]